# Moving denormalized data to Reporting DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting-services

**Current situation:**

We have a SQL database containing all of our business data. There are dozens of objects like customers, tickets and products. Each object is saved in multiple tables, usually between 8 and 12 tables per objects. So our database has way over 200 tables right now.

To make Reporting easier, we want to create a Reporting Database where we denormalize those objects to make it more accessible and improve the performance of our live DB since all reports take data from the live db right now.

**The problem:**

This is there the tricky past starts: we also need to create new columns with data in the target / reporting db where we can store calculated data for reporting. For example how long did a ticket take from start to finish or who did order a product (denormalized as text comma separated)

**The question is , what is the best solution to transfer this data to a new database?** We had different approaches in mind:

- Using a stored procedure:

Creating a sql script that transfers all defined columns to the new database using for example merge. Downside here is that it will probabely be performance heavy since all caculations would have to be done by the database itself.

- Creating a client application:

Creating a client application that selects the data from the live db, calculates all the necessary columns during runtime and inserts it into the reporting database.

- Using an SSIS job:

Which is kind of a mix between the two above: A ssis job that gets the data, calculates all extended columns and puts them into the reporting db.

I know this might be a bit of a "opinion based" questions but there has to be a best practice solution since we cant be the only ones having this need. Unfortunately I really cand find any good answer on the web.

Any advice is really apreciated!

Comment: many ETL processes are a combination of all 3 of the approaches you listed.  Have you considered first using replication to a staging database? (or use AG) Otherwise, it's likely that the ETL will put load on your source DB (the problem you are trying to avoid!). Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52449/best-possible-solution-for-reporting-mirroring-or-replication

Comment: We have considered using Always On to have a replication but unfortunately its too expensive (moneywise). But the load on the live DB could be avoided using a client application those few selects would not cost any perormance and all calculations could be done by the application server, right?

Comment: "but unfortunately its too expensive (moneywise)" - but you need another server anyway? right? ... "But the load on the live DB could be avoided using a client application those few selects would not cost any performance" - why do you think that? It's you are performing transformations those selects could still take time....

Comment: Write the output of the query into a table in the reporting server?
We have at least 3 different student management systems where I work, all of the servers are linked and there are overnight (or hourly) queries run from one of those systems to store data for reporting in a "reports database"

Comment: The ReportingDB would be on the same instance as the live database. Do you think that would be a problem? Its more a political problem, we wont get any more finaces for a new server right now so we need to work with what we have. I thought about transfering a delta every 15 minutes. A select on the last changed rows within the last 15 minutes even if we target all 200 tables would not have any inpact at all in my opinion.

Comment: "The ReportingDB would be on the same instance as the live database"  - whether that's a good design depends on several factors. And it's too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Yep, your right. But the question is more concerning moving the data to the reporting DB anyway.

Comment: I find that once data is in a database, I can usually do all the data transformations within the database.  I often implement them as views.  The database is an inherently parallel environment, so it should be more efficient to do calculations there than in a single-threaded application.  (Note:  I am quite aware that some  transformations cannot be done in the application, but I doubt these apply  in this case.)

Comment: Bigger chunk of your issue: migrate tables via business unit/processes and in the of process de-normalize or datawarehouse the tables add the additional columns that the business requires. Pros: You will keep existing reporting in place; easy to QA data. Cons: more space, resources.
Small issueTools are simple you can do everything via Stored procs (since your within sql world) or use an ETL tool (like SSIS, etc)

Comment: It looks like you are focusing on calculations and offloading these calculations to another computer. Usually the bottleneck in RDBMS is disk IO, not CPU, so it should not matter much what computer performs the calculations.

Comment: I would say that you need a combination of SP and ETL. As other users said, it would be interesting you have a "ods" database where you dump the first round of data retrieved from your operational source. Maybe this task could be supported by some SP. This "ods" could have the first round of transformations of the data and first clean up. Then, the typical approach is use an ETL tool (like SSIS) to handle the load of your analytical model, which normally is a star model where you denormalize your ods data into dimension and fact tables.

Comment: In my opinion, you should absolutely be using SSDT to to ETL the data out. Our process is to extract the raw data from the source, into a data warehouse staging area. We then have ETL jobs to process the data and transform it into a star schema in the data warehouse. This takes the processing load away from the live database, and allows us to join the data to other data sets to produce richer reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is really too broad, but I'll try and outline some of the options you have.

**Extract**

Option 1: Create stored procedures that live either in the source DB itself or in your reporting DB (using a cross database call (obviously this has downsides i.e. the databases become tied together)) that read directly from the source tables. These procedures should be able to run in both full (all the data) and incremental (just the latest) mode. You might want to do some overlapping for your incremental load too.

Option 2: You set up Change Data Capture (issues here with making sure you don't fill your logs, but this gives you a finer level of detail) or Change Tracking (Only get the latest version of the record, not the change) on your source database and read from the resulting change tables to get the changed records from the source database.

Option 3: Create a read only replica of your source database and read from this replica.

**Transform**

Option 1: My personal choice would be to use SSIS for the extract process. It's built for doing stuff like this. Especially when you're going between servers and you'll also be able to bring in data from the rest of the organisation, like HR records and such like. You should set up a framework where you have a project and each project consists of a list of SSIS packages to execute in either full or incremental mode. You can either load directly into your source database or create a middleman database in order to ready any complex data for further processing. You may need to put things down after you've picked them up to carry out some of the more complex things.

Option 2: You write stored procedures that read from source and push directly into your destination. This could be combined with Option 1 in the Extract section. You will need to ensure these can merge, so you can either use separate INSERT and UPDATE statements or use a MERGE.

**Load**

Option 1: Put your data down from the ETL process into a star or snowflake schema (star will require less joins and there are built in optimisations in SSAS for star schemas). You can then use this for moving your data into SSAS either Multidimensional or a Tabular Model.

Option 2: You put your data down in the form your reports require, by report. Obviously this can lead to a crazy amount of data sets, but it has its wins if there are only a small amount of reports required that won't change. It depends....

You really do have too much choice here as you're trying to architect an entire BI solution, and we'll all have differing ideas about what is best for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! If your interested what I ended up with have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a sort of a hybrid:

I created a Webapplication that displays all objects and tables as it looks in the object model. It allows you to select which columns of which object should be transfered, denormalized and so on. The output of this will be saved into a table listing all columns that should be available in the ReportingDB.

Saving the selected columns creates:

- A view in the LiveDB selecting all of those columns. One view per object based on the object model.
- A stored procedure that moves all data from "new" columns to the Reporting DB.
  New columns are columns that not yet have been transfered. This stored procedure gets triggered every 24 hours during the night to avoid any impact on the LiveDB.
- An "update" stored procedure that transfers updates all datarows in the ReportingDB that have an unequal datetime stamp than the ReportingDB. This SP gets triggered every 15 minutes.
- A stored procedure called "objectname"_aggregates which only will be created once.
  It allows you to add custom functions to fill aggregate columns with data. This SP gets triggered every 15 minutes right after the update SP. You are able to either calculate the content of the aggregate columns based on the columns that were transmitted or the "delta" from the old value to the new ( if you need to make complex time calculations and such... )

All stored procedures always select the data out of the view which has been created before.